# Core 2.1 APIVersioning Action ambiguity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, api-versioning

I have successfully set up API Versioning in my Core 2.1 API project.

`http://localhost:8088/api/Camps/ATL2016/speakers?api-version=x.x`

Versions `1.1` and `2.0` work but `1.0` fails with an ambiguity on the `Get(string, bool)` Actions.

ASP.NET Core Web Server:

`MyCodeCamp> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DefaultApiVersionRoutePolicy[1]
MyCodeCamp>       Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity. Matching actions: 
            MyCodeCamp.Controllers.Speakers2Controller.Get(string, bool) (MyCodeCamp)
MyCodeCamp>       MyCodeCamp.Controllers.SpeakersController.Get(string, bool) (MyCodeCamp)
MyCodeCamp> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
MyCodeCamp>       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
MyCodeCamp> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions 
        matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:`

Controller `Speakers2` is decorated with `[ApiVersion("2.0")]` so it’s `Get(string, bool)` action is version 2.0 so why can’t `Versioning` tell them apart?

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 3.0.0` (can’t install higher due to version conflicts)

Startup.cs:

```
  services.AddApiVersioning(cfg =>
    { cfg.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 1);
      cfg.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
      cfg.ReportApiVersions = true;     });
```

Controllers:

```
  [Route("api/camps/{moniker}/speakers")]
  [ValidateModel]
  [ApiVersion("1.0")]
  [ApiVersion("1.1")]
  public class SpeakersController : BaseController
  { 
    . . . 
    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public IActionResult Get(string moniker, bool includeTalks = false)

    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.1")]
    public virtual IActionResult GetWithCount(string moniker, bool includeTalks = false)

  [Route("api/camps/{moniker}/speakers")]
  [ApiVersion("2.0")]
  public class Speakers2Controller : SpeakersController
  {
    ...
    public override IActionResult GetWithCount(string moniker, bool includeTalks = false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently versioning gets confused with the multiple `Getxxx` `IActionResult`s.

I got it to work by making the `Get` action in the `Speakers` `controller` `virtual` and then `overriding` it in the `Speakers2` `controller` as a placeholder that will not be called.  I also had to apply the `[ApiVersion("2.0")]` only to the `GetWithCount` `action` and not the `controller`.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/camps/{moniker}/speakers")]
[ValidateModel]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("1.1")]
public class SpeakersController : BaseController

  [HttpGet]
  [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public virtual IActionResult Get(string moniker, bool includeTalks = false)



[Route("api/camps/{moniker}/speakers")]
public class Speakers2Controller : SpeakersController

  public override IActionResult Get(string moniker, bool includeTalks = false)
  {  return NotFound(); }

  [ApiVersion("2.0")]
  public override IActionResult GetWithCount(string moniker, bool includeTalks = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your previous implementation didn't work is because `[ApiVersion]` and `[MapToApiVersion]` are **not** inherited. This might seem counter-intuitive, but if they were, then each subclass would keep accumulating API versions. In the 2nd implementation, you didn't override the original `Get` so it implicitly became `2.0` as specified by the controller. This is why you were seeing duplicates because it's now ambiguous with `GetWithCount`.

Answer (score 0):

*Multiple candidate actions were found, but none matched the requested service API version '1'.*
Soln:
Use: >[MapToApiVersion("1.0")] attribute on your action method